# How to get Firebase FCM token outside the Swift AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a SwiftUI app and inside it's custom AppDelagte I get the FCM token and save it to my database. Which works.

But when the user registers and gets put to the main screen of the applcation, their FCM token isn't uploaded to the database until they restart the app and the AppDelagte messaging function is run again. So basically, when the user registers, the app will not function correctly until they restart the app.

I have tried to get and then send the FCM token as soon as they successfully register via:

```
Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
```

which returns an empty string, meaning it is only made after they re run the app delegate.

How do I get around this, and send the FCM token to their database profile as soon as they register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the `fcmToken` on a static property of the AppDelegate as soon as you get it and then access it whenever the user registers.

Add a static property to the app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static var fcmToken: String?

    // when you get the token set it to the static property
    Self.fcmToken = fcmToken
}
```

Then when you need the token simply access:

```
AppDelegate.fcmToken
```

Comment: I know how to do that (I haven't tried it yet, so I will try it now and see if it works), but could you add some code/example to your answer for others as I know this is a reoccuring issue for many whilst searching the internet for this anwser

Comment: And thank you, it did work, I never thought of that

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method at any time to access the token instead of storing it.

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
  } else if let token = token {
    print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
    self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text  = "Remote FCM registration token: \(token)"
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client