# Swiftui app having 2 different FCM tokens

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the fcm token with:

```
let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
```

I get the token, but this is not the same token as what the application has. I am using Swift ui.

The way that I am trying to get my fcm token:

```
@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogin")
            let isUser = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUser")
               
            let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken// here I should get the same token
            
            if(isLogin == false){
                LoginView(myFCMToken: token ?? "fcmioserrordan")
            }else
            {
                if(isUser == true){
                    UsersView(myFCMToken: token ?? "fcmioserrordan")
                }else{
                    RestaurantView(myFCMToken: token ?? "fcmioserrordan")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app delegate with the methods that add the token.
The extension AppDelegate:

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

      let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        print("Device token: ", deviceToken) // This token can be used for testing notifications on FCM
    }
}
```

**Somehow this fcmToken is different from the above Messaging.messaging().fcmToken, how is this possible?**

The AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}
```

The rest of the implementation:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
  }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is how is possible that the token from the extension to be different from let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken from the main?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Firebase FCM token outside the Swift AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918503/how-to-get-firebase-fcm-token-outside-the-swift-appdelegate)